# Unable to bind ConnectionPoolDataSource Instance

Tags: java, database, jdbc, connection-pooling

```
public static void main(String Data[])
{  
        ConnectionPoolDataSource dps;
        try 
        {
            cnt=new InitialContext();
            cnt.rebind("java:comp/env/jdbc/pool/dragon", dps);
        } '
        catch (NamingException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Following is my program to bind a ConnectionPoolDataSource object connect a database in mysql using JNDI.
On compiling it, i've got an error:

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RegistryContext: object to bind must be Remote, Reference, or Referenceable***

Now i've got the following doubts:

1. How can i create a remote object for connecting to mysql database ?
2. How can i assign the database name...etc...to that remote object ?

the `ConnectionPoolDataSource` does not provide method for setting server name, database name, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like u r trying to bind it using JNDI naming......

i suggest you something...
try c3p0 pooling....which would be easier for u.....
u can avoid using JNDI naming.....

read the tutorials from the following link and u can download the jar file.....

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/